# Redefining CLOCKS_PER_SEC to a higher number in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-10, ctime

GNU C++ Compiler in Windows 10 returns `CLOCKS_PER_SEC = 1000`, but I need to measure compiling time for an algorithm that goes below millisecond intervals (it's a school project). Is there a way to redefine `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to, say, one million (like UNIX-based OSes)? On a side note, `#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC ((clock_t)(1000000))` doesn't seem to work, either.

Comment: The value of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` doesn't change the resolution used by `clock`. Instead it's the opposite, that the resolution/precision of `clock` dictates the value of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Comment: There are many way to do timing in a C++ program, some [in the standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) and other compiler or OS specific. It should not be hard to find a solution with higher resolution when searching a little.

Comment: If you can live with a Windows specific solution, this might be interesting: [Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps). I'm not sure whether this is covered in the `std::chrono` timers. You may try this before you invest in Win API programming.

Comment: Well, this assignment absolutely requires the usage of `time.h` and `time.h` only, so I was wondering if I could implement a solution that can be achieved in the limits and boundaries of `time.h`. I'll make sure to try out the `<chrono>` library, though. Thank you!

Comment: We use `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` on Windows. (I was not yet able to port this old code to `std::chrono`.) In the past, we recognized a usual resolution of round-about 17 ms. Once, this was not precise enough anymore, we used the MS' multi-media API to improve the clock resolution. Currently, I see measurements with 1 ms resolution, sometimes even 0.5 ms (although I don't trust the sub-milli-secs too much).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer : **no**.

Long answer : No **but** you can use the [QueryPerformanceCounter function](http://LARGE_INTEGER%20StartingTime,%20EndingTime,%20ElapsedMicroseconds;%20LARGE_INTEGER%20Frequency;%20%20QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency);%20%20QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);%20%20//%20Activity%20to%20be%20timed%20%20QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);%20ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart%20=%20EndingTime.QuadPart%20-%20StartingTime.QuadPart;%20%20%20//%20//%20We%20now%20have%20the%20elapsed%20number%20of%20ticks,%20along%20with%20the%20//%20number%20of%20ticks-per-second.%20We%20use%20these%20values%20//%20to%20convert%20to%20the%20number%20of%20elapsed%20microseconds.%20//%20To%20guard%20against%20loss-of-precision,%20we%20convert%20//%20to%20microseconds%20*before*%20dividing%20by%20ticks-per-second.%20//%20%20ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart%20*=%201000000;%20ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart%20/=%20Frequency.QuadPart;), heres an example off of MSDN :

```
LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime, ElapsedMicroseconds;
LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;

QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency); 
QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);

// Activity to be timed

QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;


//
// We now have the elapsed number of ticks, along with the
// number of ticks-per-second. We use these values
// to convert to the number of elapsed microseconds.
// To guard against loss-of-precision, we convert
// to microseconds *before* dividing by ticks-per-second.
//

ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000;
ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
```

That way, you can even measure nanoseconds but beware : at that precision level, even the tick count can drift and jitter so you might never receive a **perfectly** accurate result. If you want perfect precision i guess you will be forced to use an [RTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) on appropriate, specialized hardware which is shielded against [soft errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_error), for example

Comment: I was able to use this for precision, and as the edit said, got fluctuating result, so I just decided to loop all the stuff about 50 times (lol) and get statistical results. Thanks for the help!

Comment: btw, i did a bit of digging ... for anyone reading this, interested in near-perfect precision : FreeRTOS supports interrupt priorities higher than kernel-priority which effectively disables each and every delay because of the OS, giving the programmer absolute, unmigitated, undistorted control over the hardware and software. This is possible on supported platforms only : https://www.freertos.org/a00110.html#kernel_priority

Answer (score 2):

> Well, this assignment absolutely requires the usage of `time.h` and `time.h` only

In this case, measuring short times is hard, but making short times longer is easy... Just repeat your algorithm until you reach, say, 1 second, and then divide the measured time by the number of iterations you did. You may get a skewed picture for cache-related and branch predictor-related times (as repeated iterations will "warm up" the caches and teach the branch predictor), but for the rest it should be decently accurate.

Incidentally, notice that using `clock()` is a bit problematic, as *by standard* it measures user CPU time of the current process (so, kernel time and IO wait is excluded), although on Windows it measures wall clock time. That's essentially the same as long as your algorithm is CPU-bound and manages to run pretty much continuously, but you may in for big differences if it is IO-bound or if it is running on a busy system

If you are interested in wall clock time and you are restricted to `time.h`, your best option is plain old `time()`; in that case I'd sync up precisely to the change of second with a busy wait, and then measure the number of iterations in a few seconds as said before.

```
time_t start = time(nullptr);
while(start == time(nullptr));
start = time(nullptr);
int i = 0;
while(time(nullptr) - start < 5) {
    // your algorithm
    ++i;
}
int elapsed = time(nullptr) - start;
double time_per_iteration = double(elapsed) / i;
```

Comment: Well I guess professors _would_ expect this type of measurement from a typical sophomore. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @K.Paul: a serious sophomore would also add an extra external loop and a mean-stddev measurement to understand the precision of such measurement ;-)